# How to close Debug tool window in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

[image: This is the Image]

Whenever I open my IntelliJ to write a code the debug tool window is open and I'm unable to write any code the image link is referred to above. How can I close this window?

Comment: Can you close the popup with Esc, or click to the editor?

Comment: You could also try dragging to the tabs at the bottom of the IntelliJ window